# Return more then One field from database SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

This line:

```
used_emails = [row.email for row
           in db.execute(select([halo4.c.email], halo4.c.email!=''))]
```

Returns:

```
['first.last@domain.com', 'first.last@domain.com', 'first.last@domain.com', 'first.last@domain.com', 'first.last@domain.com']
```

I use this to find a match:

```
if recipient in used_emails:
```

If it finds a match I need to pull another field (halo4.c.code) from the database in the same row. Any suggestions on how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

I'll caveat this by saying my SQLAlchemy experience is limited (so apologies if this is way off base), but when you get your results, would it be feasible to create a dictionary (instead of a list), keyed by `email`, with the value representing all of the data in the row (`SELECT *`)? That way if you find a matching email, you could reference the value at that key and pull the data you need (i.e `halo4.c.code`). This should save you another database hit as the value would exist in your dictionary.

In Python 2.7, something like:

```
used_emails = {row.email: row.code for row in select([halo4.c.email, halo4.c.code], halo4.c.email != '')}
```

Or in Python 2.6:

```
used_emails = dict(
    (row.email, row.code) for row in db.execute(
        select([halo4.c.email, halo4.c.code]halo4.c.email!='')))
```

You could then use something like:

```
if recipient in used_emails:
    # This may not be the proper syntax - happy to troubleshoot if not
    print used_emails[recipient]
```

Comment: Seems like the right idea. It errors out and says the `:` in `[row.email:` is `SyntaxError: invalid syntax`.

Comment: That was with `[` instead of `{`. When I switched it back to the way you suggested it says the `for` in `row for row` was `SyntaxError: invalid syntax`

Comment: @DavidNeudorfer Python 2.6 by any chance? I'll update with something that will work with that.

Comment: @DavidNeudorfer Also, once we get it working, I'll update with the correct SQLAlchemy syntax, since this may not be 100% spot-on :)

Comment: @RocketDonket Yes. Python 2.6.6

Comment: I tried the 2.6 code you posted and got `TypeError: '_BinaryExpression' object is not iterable`

Comment: @DavidNeudorfer Okay, must be a SQLAlchemy-specific issue. I will set up a quick demo environment in a little bit and see if I can get it working.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/19062/discussion-between-david-neudorfer-and-rocketdonkey)

Comment: @DavidNeudorfer Updated with what ended up working for you from our discussion. Glad you got it sorted out!